# Aspect before not being called

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I have looked through tutorials and answer here. The message under the log method doesn't print.

The IDE identifies that the path for Wrapper annotation is correct when used over the log method. But it shows that my log method is never used.

(Using Intellij Ultimate, assuming it would identify that the log method is used if the Aspect is configured correctly). Added a screenshot of my file structure if needed.

At present it only prints the messages from the general method. 
Is it my configuration? Please advice. Thanks.

```
//main class
@SpringBootApplication
public class AspecttestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AspecttestApplication.class, args);

        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.general();
    }
}

//class to implement aspect
public class SomeClass {

    @Wrapper(name = "GENERAL")
    void general(){
        System.out.println("general start ..");
        System.out.println("general end ..");
    }

}

//Aspect
@Aspect
@Component
public class MainHelper {

    @Before("@annotation(Wrapper)")
    void log(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("log called from aspect");
    }
}

//Config
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class LogConfig {
    //i don't have anything to config
    //solely using this to EnableAspectJAutoProxy
}

//Annotation
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Wrapper {
    String name() default "DEFAULT";
}
```

[Screenshot for file format under ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOCfR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP aspects works only on spring beans methods called from Bean fetched from spring context (e.g. by injection).

In this example you can add @Component annotation on SomeClass and change main method to

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AspecttestApplication.class, args);

    SomeClass someClass = context.getBean(SomeClass.class);
    someClass.general();
```

to see `log called from aspect` log.

You can read more at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop